# \$\delta n \cdot x + n \cdot \delta x~\$ equation of shrunk coil with incremented number of turns per unit length

Tags: current, electromagnetism, coil, solenoid, homework

The very long coil exists with the following information .

$$  a:=\text{radius of the circle of the coil}  $$

$$  n:=\text{number of turns of the coil per unit length}  $$

$$  x:=\text{length of the coil (not a length of the wire )}  $$

$$  N:=nx ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{total number of turns of the coil}  $$

$$  I:=\text{current which is to be flown to the coil}  $$

We want to know the force of shrink of the coil .

$$  H=nI  ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{magnetic field inside the coil }  $$

$$  \Phi=\underbrace{\mu_{0}H}_{\text{Wb}/\text{m} ^{2} }  \cdot \underbrace{\pi a ^{2}}_{\text{m}^{2} }  \cdot \underbrace{nx}_\text{turns}  ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{interlinkage magnetic flux}  $$

$$  U_{\text{m} } = \frac{1}{2} I \Phi_{}  ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{energy}  $$

\$~ \delta x ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{extent of length of shrink}  ~\$

\$~ \delta n ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{incremented number of turns per unit length as shrink is done }  ~\$

What I can't get currently is the below equation .

$$  \delta n \cdot x + n \cdot \delta x =0 $$

What should I consider first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what class you are taking or if this is self-education (which I applaud, if so.) And I certainly have zero knowledge of any context you've acquired before reaching this point. But I can read equations.

I think the idea here is that \$\partial\:\Phi=0\$ (the flux itself isn't changing.) Since the flux isn't changing, it follows that neither is \$\Phi_{_0}=\mu_{_0}H\pi a^2\$ (which, of course, is the static flux under consideration.)

So, given \$\Phi=\Phi_{_0}\cdot nx\$, and applying the derivative operator:

$$\begin{align*}D\:\Phi &= D\:\left\{\Phi_{_0}\cdot nx\right\}
\\\\
&= \Phi_{_0}\cdot D\:\left\{ nx\right\}
\\\\
&=\Phi_{_0}\cdot \left[D\:\left\{ n\right\}\cdot x+D\:\left\{ x\right\}\cdot n\right]
\\\\
\partial\:\Phi&= \Phi_{_0}\cdot \left[\partial n\cdot x+\partial x\cdot n\right]
\end{align*}$$

Given the static situation, you know that \$\partial\:\Phi=0\$, so:

$$\begin{align*}
0&= \Phi_{_0}\cdot \left[\partial n\cdot x+\partial x\cdot n\right]
\end{align*}$$

And since \$\Phi_{_0}\$ cannot be assumed to be zero, it follows that the only remaining factor must be zero:

$$\begin{align*}
0&= \partial n\cdot x+\partial x\cdot n
\end{align*}$$